# Can "during which" be used in this context

Tags: commas, academia

The text comes for an academic publication and thus it should be as close to perfect grammar and    unambiguous as possible. I am introducing a set of properties and if not self evident also defining them.
Can "during which" be used in a case:

> ..., time window during which the action must take place, ...

or do I need to say:

> ..., time window that is the time interval, in which the action must take place, ...

That extra comma would break the nice structure: "thing1, thing2 and thing3"

Comment: I would hazard that *time window* is a common-enough expression not to need explanation. But what about a structure like "...Thing 1, time window (the time interval in which the action must occur), Thing 3..."?

Comment: Brackets are kind of extra information that should not add anything that must be. The amount of rigorousness is silly, I think, but still, I got a correction request when I left it undefined.

Comment: Put the definition of *time window* in a footnote. Wouldn't any pedant determined to include an unnecessary definition be delighted with a footnote?

Comment: That could also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Time window* is a reasonable phrase. If you wanted an alternate phrase, consider *time interval* or perhaps *time span*/*timespan*.

I find the second construct somewhat awkward, but if you opted for it, the commas would be placed here:

> ...; time window, that is, the interval in which the action must take place;

In general, if you find that you need to list numerous comma-separated items which may, themselves, contain commas, [you can use semicolons](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/02/lists-part-2-commas-and-semicolons.html) as list separators, like such:

> They included an apple, sliced into spirals, not chunks; nutmeg, freshly ground; and a stick of butter, unsalted.

Comment: The word time window has been somewhat a widely accepted meaning in the literature. But within different cases it may have a slightly different meaning. The rigorousness is absolute. No-one should be capable by any means have a possibility to interpret it wrong, even if they would  deliberately try to do so. Semicolons might work.